# BIM 360 Field Forge - Retrieve Container ID

Tags: postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

I am ultimately trying to build a custom integration with BIM360 Field to track and monitor field issues generated on a specific project.

Currently in the trial stage I am using Postman to make URI calls, mostly based on Sam Nseir's post [Export BIM 360 Project Data via Autodesk Forge](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/sam-nseir-export-bim-360-project-data-autodesk-forge)

I have everything from that post working correctly, Authentication, Projects list, and was able to extract my Hub Id with a `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs` call.

I am getting hung up trying to determine my Container ID based on this [Forge Help Doc](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/retrieve-container-id/). I am only ever able to return a empty Data set `"data":[]` as shown in the output image below. I have tried adapting the filter logic from the help docs, but end up with the exact same result.

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI2aW.jpg)

I am using an Autodesk sample project, which I am the account admin of, so I don't believe permissions should be an issue. My custom integration has Account admin, and Document management access.

Comment: It might be caused by the Autodesk account you logged into for fetching three-legged token or the `x-user-id` you passed to the POST body with the two-legged token, please make sure that your user account (Autodesk ID) has permissions to access BIM360 projects on the Web UI.

Comment: I verified that the Forge client ID is correctly recorded in the custom integration tab of the Forge account Admin, and that the BIM 360 Account ID, Client ID (same as recorded in account admin), and client secret are all correct.

When making the _https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects_ call I can return my project id, project name, start date, end date, etc. just fine.

Comment: Are there any projects belongs to the user account you logged into the Forge three-legged auth page?